# Commenting, upvoting, posting,... doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Here comes a question from [RyanRogers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/110109/ryanrogers):

> Preview, commenting, upvoting, accepting answer, posting all not working.
>
> When I try to ask a new question, edit a question, or answer a question on main or meta, the auto preview doesn't work, the tags and title fields don't give a list of tags and titles, clicking "submit" just moves me to the top of the page. Ironically, this means I can't even post on meta about this issue.
>
> When I click the "accept" check mark on an answer to my question, nothing happens. "Favourite" and "upvote" are also unresponsive.
>
> Clicking "add comment" doesn't work. It just brings me to the top of the page.
>
> These problems are present in both Firefox and Chrome.
>
> I've verified that all java plugins are enabled in both browsers. I've cleared the cache in both browsers. No change.

(Obviously, RyanRogers can't post this question; that's why I did it. The text is copied from this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574130/does-weak-convergence-with-uniformly-bounded-densities-imply-absolute-continuity).)

Comment: Can it have anything to do with [this](http://stackstatus.net/post/68056965958/projected-outages-today-november-25-2013)?

Comment: @DanielR Probably not, RyanRogers has this problem already for several days.

Comment: The OP in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572470/evaluate-i-int-gamma-0-1-fraczdzz2-4z12-using-taylors-theorem) seems to be suffering from something related to that.

Answer (score 4):

Somehow the problem has fixed itself. After playing around with java plugins and clearing the cache with no success, I just gave up for several days. Suddenly everything works.

I hope this doesn't happen to anyone else because I have no advice on how to fix the issue other than to clear the cache and wait a few days.

Thanks to saz for posting this question on meta for me.